# Can get cleaned_data when customyzing LoginView in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, captcha

Beginner with Django 3.2. I'm trying to add a Recaptcha V3 from Google on my login screen.

- I'am using [django-recaptcha3](https://github.com/kbytesys/django-recaptcha3) well configured
- The logo is showing on my login page
- When debugging the json response when calling ReCaptchaField.clean is OK !

The problem is that the form is not validated
"*'CustomAuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'*"

Error occured when I do

```
form.is_valid() # FALSE !!
captcha_score = form.cleaned_data['captcha'].get('score')
print("SCORE" + str(captcha_score))
```

Here is my code :

**In urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CustomLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

**In Forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from snowpenguin.django.recaptcha3.fields import ReCaptchaField

class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

**In Views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .forms import CustomAuthenticationForm
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CustomAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                captcha_score = form.cleaned_data['captcha'].get('score')
                print("SCORE" + str(captcha_score))
        return super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    form_class = CustomAuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
```

request.POST gives

> <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
> ['TGoQaJTZACp4MbwB3iGVVdL4IHbqWDQaIhE1ldb9M8fkpjSRDHV7l1A1tTb62f3B'],
> 'g-recaptcha-response':
> ['03AGdBq270w7Z23MTavtAHLAUNSY9IWKuVpFZe0eueIiXimW6BvhTeWKANQQIFj43m903GA-cUA-dXZm7I6br.......5Z9vdM6RY9v-Kk1ZLX1uwH5nSoc7ksWUQuA00w0T8'],
> 'username': ['remi@XXXXXe.fr'], 'password': ['vXXXXX']}>

which is normal. form.is_valid() is failing and I suspect ***form = CustomAuthenticationForm(request.POST)*** to be the problem but I don't know how to do.

Thanks a lot for your help,

--- EDIT ---

1. As you can see here in the debugger username / password are strings... Don't know why pycharm convert it in array. [image: https://ibb.co/nPVdzNp]
2. Same problem after adding

---

```
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    class Meta(AuthenticationForm):
        model = CustomUser
```

and deleting

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Comment: Interesting, why `username` and `password` fields in your form data are arrays?

Comment: Also, if you get to that line where you have `form.cleaned_data` (an exception is happening ta that line, right?) the only way you can get there is if `form.is_valid()` returned true, so the form is valid.

Comment: Don't know why it's array. form.is_valid() is FALSE.

Comment: I get the "CustomAuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'" when I omit the IF condition. if form.is_valid(): and I do form.is_valid() alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from the package **django-recaptcha3**

1. Validation occured after post method, I can use form_valid

---

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        captcha_score = form.cleaned_data['captcha']
        print("SCORE " + str(captcha_score))
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

2. In ***snowpenguin\django\recaptcha3\fields.py*** I changed
   **return values[0]** line 63 in **return json_response['score']**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Two moments here:

1. `username` and `password` fields in your form data are arrays, this is wrong - you need to check how you make POST request to Django and send strings, not arrays.
2. Since username/pass fields are arrays (not strings) - `form.is_valid` returns `False`, and if the form is *invalid* there will be *no* `cleaned_data` attribute cause it appears only when the form is valid and actually has some valid data.

Comment: it seems to pass strings, I think it's the copy/paste in pycharm that convert it in array. form.is_valid() is False but it login well...

Comment: this may mean that username/pass are incorrect. While you have your login form in invalid state - there will be no "cleaned_data" attribute.

Comment: Sadly the user/password is correct and it connects well. Admin console is telling me that i'm logged as superadmin.

Comment: The redirection for logging is also working.

Comment: Add `print (form.errors)` in your code right after `form.is_valid()` and before checking `form.cleaned_data`. This will show why exactly your form is invalid.

Comment: **form.errors is** empty but maybe the problem is that I override : def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): and the validation occured later.